# display images on specific keyword php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, position

There is a form. It has **text area**,a **text field** and an upload image option.

I want that if the user writes some paragraph and wants the image to be displayed exactly above next paragraph, then he/she write a unique keyword like 'imagehere' in **text area as well as in text field**.
this unique text would be stored in another column.

Then while retriving the text from database, if there is such keyword then replace it with

`<img src="path">`

tag

Is this correct way to display images according to position  defined by user?

Comment: You realize that It will be too hard to place the image perfectly, your html display will be different from your textarea, and to display an image in the middle of the text .. is ugly.

Comment: if all the images are displayed at bottom, then how to show which image is relevant to which paragraph? (I mean without writing like refer to figure 1,figure 2 like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!
I wanted to do this to avoid asking the user to write

```
<img src="photos/uploadedimage">
```

in textarea.
So if the user writes specific keyword then 
by using
**str_replace**, you can easily replace the specific keyword with
img src tag
and these images are displayed.